# Slow AAD Differential Query for

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

The Azure AD differential query works well and fast when we query the difference between actual Azure AD and previous state not older than 30-60 minutes. But when we query for a week ago or month ago – it takes 10 minutes to return changes – even if Azure directory is small and there are 3-4 changed attributes for this period of time, what is very slow. Is it expected behavior? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test, it is not a expected behavior. My first differential query request stated at 10/10/2016. And today I test the differential query REST using the **Fiddler** cost about 30 seconds.

To narrow this issue, I suggest that you call the other service or call this REST in different network to ensure the issue is not caused by the network. Other Azure Graph REST is also recommend to test to see whether the issue is Azure Active Directory related.

Answer (score -1):

For sure it's not... I can query 21K users in 3-4 minutes over a 24 Mbit DSL with partial properties (only those I want) and less than 10 minutes for all properties (and objects have almost all properties set so deserialization if fully in effect)

Delta queries, a few seconds, always.

Are you using your own routine over a basic HTTP client or are you using classes provided in the MS.Azure.AD assembly?

Comment: That can be a comment not an answer.